# jQuery: Generate valid tag of string

Tags: jquery, string, replace

I am looking for a way to generate a valid tag (string with only a-z and minus as valid chars) out of a given string.

Just let me show you the code:

```
<p>
    <label>Tag Title *:</label>
    <input type="text" class="tag_title" name="input_tag_title" value="" />
</p>
<p>
    <label>Tag (A-Z; -) *:</label>
    <input type="text" class="tag" name="input_tag" value="" />
</p>
```

As soon as Tag title looses focus, the Tag input box shall be filled with a valid string. It should only contain characters a-z (regardless of case) and a minus. But this should only take place if the tag-input is empty. If it is not empty, the entered string (in the tag input field) shall be checked for invalid chars and automatically replace all non-valid characters (replace all non-alphabetical characters with minuses).

I tried it with

```
$(".tag_title").blur(
    function()
    {
        $(".tag").text = this.value.replace(/[^a-z\-]/g, '_');
    }
);
```

But that does not work. Any hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.val(...)` to change the value of a text input.

I also used `.val()` against the `.tag_title` element (wrapped in a jQuery object) that received the `blur` event to get the value the user typed.

**Test it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/8mqzd/

```
$(".tag_title").blur(
    function() {
        var $tag = $('.tag');
        if( $tag.val() == "" ) {
            $tag.val( $(this).val().replace(/[^a-z\-]/g, '-') );
        }
    }
);​
```

http://api.jquery.com/val/

**EDIT:** Made it so it only replaces if the `.tag` element is empty (as requested).

**EDIT:** As **Nick** pointed out, your use of `this.value` to retrieve the value of the element that received the `blur` was just fine. I changed it to use jQuery's `.val()`, but please don't take from that the idea that you *must* use `.val()`. :o)

Comment: +1 - Note that `$(this).val()` or `this.value` is fine for an `<input type="text" />`, the second is actually much faster ;)

Comment: @Nick - But... that's... not jQuery! ;o) You're right. I do like the idea of using the native API when it's simple to do so. Not sure why I chose to change it. I'll make a note. Thanks for the + . :o)

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that an input element needs to the jQuery val() function

```
$(".tag").text = this.value.replace(/[^a-z\-]/g, '_');
```

could be like this:

```
var t = $('.tag');
t.val(t.val().replace(/[^a-z\-]/g, '_'));
```

EDIT: Thanks digitalFresh, I've reviewed and made changes.

Comment: `this` cannot be used because the function is executing globally. Use
`$(".tag").text($(".tag").text().replace(/[^a-z\-]/g, '_'));`. (maybe)

Comment: @digitalFresh - Not sure where that idea came from, it's certainly not executed globally, `this` refers to the `<input type="text" class="tag_title" name="input_tag_title" value="" />` element inside it's `blur` handler.